# correct word choice: garner or acquire fame, popularity and praise

Tags: vocabulary

(1) The actor **garnered/acquired** **fame** early in his career.

(2) His novelty **garnered/acquired** **popularity** shortly after it was released.

(3) The writer **garnered/acquired** **praise** for his book on the latest developments of physics.

Which word choice works in my examples?

Comment: What do you hope to learn from an answer to this question? While both words **could** be used in any of those sentences, I would not choose to use either of them. Other options include achieved, rose to, gained, earned, Have you looked at the dictionary definitions of these words in a good dictionary? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acquire https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/garner

Comment: They all work. What are you asking?

Comment: "Garner" has the connotation of actively sought and achieved, whereas "acquired" is more general -- acquired by dint of effort or by luck, for example.